# Can you compare groups over time if data has been collected at different time points?

Tags: trend, mixed-model, test-for-trend

If have two groups with follow-up measures of a normally-distributed continues outcome measure. One group is measured at 4 time points with unequal intervals. The other group is measured at 7 time points with unequal intervals. Time points for both groups fall within  100 days from baseline, but don't overlap between groups. E.g.:

**Group 1**, measured at days: 1, 10, 50, 90

**Group 2**, measured at days: 1, 15, 30, 40, 60, 75, 95

*Is there any way I can compare the slopes of the two groups?*

I have used linear mixed models (xtmixed in Stata) but the trend tests tell me that the contrast is not estimable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I entered the measurements as factors that work for pairwise comparisons (if time points are identical). I was able to compare the slopes by entering time as continues variable.